# Render react component based on user permissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a component **based on the user role.**

For example:
If the user is a sales persons he would see both buttons.
But if he is support he would see only the second button.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from './MyCustomButton';

class App extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Button> // visible only for sales manager
          Action A
        </Button>
        <Button> // visible for support and sales manager
          Action B
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

I would really like to avoid if-else statements inside the render. Keep it clean as possible.

Is there a good design or some tools/decorator that could be useful here?

I've already handled it in the server side but I need a clean solution for the client side as well.

thanks.

Comment: I hesitate to write an answer as this is a much more complicated system than I can do justice in stack overflow. There are react conditional ways to render, but you could look at decorating the component with a permission system similar to how you would model on the backend

Comment: How important is it for you to not use conditionals inside of `render`? Because it would be the most straightforward way to achieve what you want and a very common pattern in react.

Comment: @jotaen i prefer not inside the render.

Comment: @IdanDagan give my answer a look. You will have to do a conditional in the render at some point in time or another. But what you can do is minimize that a lot by writing an auth function around your component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could do this is with an Authorizor component. It would be a very simple function that does your validation for you like normal, and just checks an authLevel. If you need to adjust this to work with your auth model thats fine.

```
function Authorizor(props) {
  if (props.authLevel > props.user.authLevel) {
    return null;
  }
  const { ComponentToValidate } = props;
  return <ComponentToValidate {...props} />;
}
```

then usage would be something like

```
<Authorizor authLevel={1} ComponentToValidate={Button} {...this.props} />
```

in your example this would look like.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Authorizor authLevel={2} ComponentToValidate={Button} label="Action A" onClick={this.handleActionAThingy} {...this.props} />
        <Authorizor authLevel={1} ComponentToValidate={Button} label="Action B" onClick={this.handleActionBThingy} {...this.props} />
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can inline ternary statements directly into your component tree, as shown below. If these boolean expression would evaluate to `false`, react will skip them automatically.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    const user = this.props.user;
    return (
      <Grid>
        {user.isSalesManager && <Button>
          Action A
        </Button>}
        {(user.isSalesManager || user.isSupport) && <Button>
          Action B
        </Button>}
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

In order to do that, you need to have the information about the user role in the props though.

Read more on conditional rendering in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: Note that this answer was written before the OP added the constraint to the question that he doesn’t want to use if/else inside his render. In that respect, my answer wouldn’t really meet the question, since I’m using ternaries here, which are conditionals as well. I would still consider the way here as very common and “native” in react.

Answer (score 1):

Short code

```
 render() {   
      const button1 = <Button>Action A</Button>; // visible only for sales manager
      const button2 = <Button>Action B</Button>; // visible for support and sales manager

      return (
         <Grid>
           {[user.type === 'salesManager' ? button1 : null, button2]}
         </Grid>
      )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of 'cleaner' look and not lack of condition (because you will have to have it somewhere) you could create simple reusable component:

```
const Visibility = ({ isVisible, children }) => (
  isVisible ? React.Children.only(children) : null;
)
```

and use it like that

```
      <Grid>
        <Visibility isVisible={user.isSalesManager}>
          <Button> // visible only for sales manager
            Action A
          </Button>
        </Visibility>
        <Visibility isVisible={user.isSalesManager || user.isSupport}>
          <Button> // visible for support and sales manager
            Action B
          </Button>
        </Visibility>
      </Grid>
```

it's hard to come up with much better solution without knowing more about your application architecture, but if you keep your user roles in some kind of store accessible from anywhere (redux, context, whatever) you could create very similar component that accepts roles needed to see it's children (let's say an array of strings) and possibly some kind of descriptor (like `all`, `oneOf` etc. if your permissions system is more complicated) and component itself grabs needed data from global store and compares it to props it got. If that's your use case i can provide example.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use like following in these kind of scenarios

```
render(){
var buttonADiv = <Button> // visible only for sales manager
          Action A
        </Button> ;

var buttonBDiv = <Button> // visible for support and sales manager
          Action B
        </Button> ;

var rows = [];

if(user === 'sales'){
    rows.push(buttonADiv);
    rows.push(buttonBDiv);
}
else if(user === 'support'){
    rows.push(buttonBDiv);
}

return (
      <Grid>
        {rows}
      </Grid>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from './MyCustomButton';

class App extends React.PureComponent {

   render() {
      if(user.type = 1){
      return (

      );
      }
      else if(user.type = 2){
      return (

     );
     }
  }
}
```